# converting jQuery to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help converting this jQuery to pure JavaScript, It's the last one I have to convert so that I can remove jQuery completely from my project.

```
function hoverFunc(e) {
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, opacity: 1, scale: 0});
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, scale: 0.5});
}

function unhoverFunc(e) {
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, opacity: 1, scale: 1});
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, scale: 1});
}

$("a").hover(hoverFunc, unhoverFunc);
```

Comment: Are you looking for `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to illustrate Hien's example with an inline code example so you can run the code snippet below and see it working. Here I have added 3 links and the hover function adds 2 separate classes to the link which are then removed by the unhover function.

```js
var atags= document.querySelectorAll('a');

function hoverFunc(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('hover', 'test')
}
function unhoverFunc(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('hover', 'test')
}

atags.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverFunc);
  link.addEventListener('mouseleave', unhoverFunc);
})
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
}
a.hover {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}
a.test {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">Link 1</a>
<a href="/">Link 2</a>
<a href="/">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: You solution worked and you were the first one that answered it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and `addEventListener` to mouseover/mouseleave as

```
 var atags= document.querySelectorAll('a');

    atags.forEach(function(a) {
      a.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverFunc);
      a.addEventListener('mouseleave', unhoverFunc);
    })
```

Comment: What’s the difference in “link” or “input”?

Comment: it is only name you set

Comment: Thank you, yours worked but Jon answered first and both your answers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
function hoverFunc(e) {
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, opacity: 1, scale: 0});
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, scale: 0.5});
}

function unhoverFunc(e) {
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, opacity: 1, scale: 1});
  gsap.to(ball, {duration: 0.3, scale: 1});
}

var a = documet.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].mouseover = hover;
  a[i].mouseout = unhover;
}
```

Comment: So first error I got was "x" not defined. So I replaced it with: "var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');" I didnt get any errors but it didn't work.